# Use volume mounting for app behind Nginx with shared volume access

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've got a Python web app that runs inside two Docker containers, one for the FastAPI backend, the other for the Vue.JS front-end (and there's besides a third one, with the Postgres Db). To enable access to the front-end (for image uploads) from the back-end, I should need to use Docker volumes.

My Docker compose file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  use_frontend:
    container_name: 'use_frontend'
    # --> ADDED <--
    volumes:
      - 'myshare:/etc/nginx'
      - 'myshare:/usr/share/nginx/html'
    build: 
      context: ./admin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - use_backend
    ports:
      - 8090:80

  use_db:
    container_name: use_db
    image: postgres:14.2
    # etc etc...

  use_backend:
    container_name: 'use_backend'
    volumes:
      # --> ADDED <--
      - 'myshare:/usr/share/nginx/html'
    build: 
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - use_db
    # etc etc...

# --> ADDED <--
volumes:
  myshare:
    driver: local
```

The `Dockerfile` for `use_frontend` hasn't changed (must it?)

```mk
FROM node:16.14.2 as builder

WORKDIR /admin

# copy out files for npm
COPY package*.json ./
COPY vite.config.js ./

# install and build Vue.js
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Nginx image
FROM nginx:1.21

# copy Nginx conf file to VOLUME mounted folder
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# clean everything in VOLUME mounted folder (app entry point)
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# copy compiled app to to VOLUME mounted folder (app entry point)
COPY --from=builder /admin/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# expose port 80 for HTTP access
EXPOSE 80

# run Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The Nginx conf file hasn't changed either:

```python
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        # app entry point
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # MIME types
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        # etc etc...
    }
}
```

But after doing

```sh
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

I'm getting `file not found` errors from Nginx:

```
use_frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
use_frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
use_frontend  | 2022/07/24 23:21:32 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
use_frontend  | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong with the Docker volume mounting?

Comment: In the Dockerfile of the Frontend you are putting nginx.conf in the /etc/nginx folder. 
And after the build the volumes are mounted, where you overwrite your /etc/nginx folder in the frontend-Container with the contents of myshare (on the Host). 
So, the contents of myshare are in /etc/nginx folder in the container. 
Remove the 'myshare:/etc/nginx' line and it's probably working ok.

Comment: This helped remove the error, But the main app page at localhost:8090 displays an empty Nginx placeholder instead of the index page.

Comment: I am now getting this error:
```
[error] 31#31: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8090", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8090/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reaction on comment on problem description above:

And ignore the favicon errors. There's just no favicon probably.

If you only removed the myshare volume mapping, then there's still no file in /usr/share/nginx/html.

Your try_files says:

1. Try the url you are given ($uri)
2. If not found, then go to index.html in the same folder.
   And since that's also not found, it loops around.

For the server part in nginx.conf I use the following:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
          # Next 2 lines are important. Otherwise 404 error
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html;

          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
```

And in a new directory, next to the docker-compose, create a directory called static_site.

In static_site create an index.html with following contents:

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

And add the following in the docker-compose, volumes section:

```
    volumes:
      - 'myshare:/etc/nginx'
      - './static_site:/usr/share/nginx/html'
```

(Sorry, quick and dirty solution to check if nginx is working and mappings are working)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the check. In the mean time I've written an article on the subject which explains it in more detail: https://bertcatsburg.github.io/docs/category/nginx-in-docker/